# Process getting killed by SIGKILL

Tags: debian, kernel

I am running an algorithm on a server and the algorithm takes long time to get finished. But for some reason, the process is getting killed automatically. I am not sure exactly the reason for it and upon googling, I found some scripts which can give me more information.

```
./temp.sh: line 2: 30539 Killed                  ./process file1
Got SIGNAL 9
process was killed with SIGKILL
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

I tried googling this but I am not sure what the log message means or how to rectify it. Can anyone tell me why the process is getting killed and how to stop it?

I am using 4.9.0-6-amd64 kernel and Debian 9

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose this type of problem.  But if I had to guess, I'd check to see if you're blowing resource limits (memory usage, CPU allowance).  Is this a server you own or running on some form of cloud?

Comment: It is a server my company owns. So I run htop in another ssh terminal window and monitor? Thanks for your comment nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say exactly as you don't give enough information. Some things you can try is:

1) `dmesg` should tell you if [OOM Killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) was activated because your overall system memory was running out.

2) `cat /var/log/messages` can help identify process related problems, you can try and filter only errors from there

If it is not any of these 2 then it's probably an issue in your application, like calling `kill`. Another thing to mention is ([signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)):

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or
>         ignored.

So there is a good chance that it is coming from the kernel because of some violation of your program.